# How do I delete a specific row from sqlite with Android Studio (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I looked through so many tutorials and it's still not working for me. I have a database that looks like this:
[databaseImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdXeB.png)
Note that the actual row does not match up with the id. I would like to delete from the actual row rather than using the id.

I have the following function:

```
`fun deleteDBData(TABLE_NAME:String, rowID : Int) {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "$ID_COL=$rowID", null)
}`
```

This however, deletes using the number in the id column rather than the actual row. So with this function, if I tell it to delete rowID = 4, it will delete row 1 rather than row 4. How do I get sqlite to delete row 4?

Comment: I don't know how you can solve this problem but highly recommend you to use Room for database. Not only it's so much easier, but also more people can help you with your problems.

Comment: Whichever column value that you are keying on that tells you which row you want to delete, use a where clause that equates that column with the key value.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling to delete the row that has the ID_COL = 4
To delete the 4th row you can run a query like

```
delete from tran_log where id in (select id from tran_log limit 1 offset 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `id` of the `n`th row with `LIMIT 1` and `OFFSET n - 1` after the `ORDER BY` clause which I assume should use the column `id` to sort the rows:

```
fun deleteDBData(TABLE_NAME: String, n: Long) {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    db.delete(
        TABLE_NAME,
        "$ID_COL = (SELECT $ID_COL FROM $TABLE_NAME ORDER BY $ID_COL LIMIT 1 OFFSET ? - 1)",
        arrayOf(n.toString())
    )
    db.close()
}
```